# NTC spice model

Tags: ltspice, thermistor

Hi I am trying to simulate Vishays thermistor: [NTCLE413E2103F520L](http://www.vishay.com/docs/29078/ntcle413.pdf) using LTSpice XVII. I am referring to [Application note](http://www.vishay.com/docs/29170/ltspice.pdf) and the [LTSpice model](http://www.vishay.com/doc?29171) by them to simulate it.

When I am trying to run the model after making changes to the circuit (Symbol for an NTC Thermistor and Symbol for a TFPT RTD only), I receive an error:

[image: Error Message]

I am not sure what I should do. Am I not suppose to change the parameters? Am I making a mistake while changing the model? Should there be further changes in the model to use it?

Comment: It looks like you didn't include the subcircuit. This is done using the `.inc` or `.lib` SPICE directives, followed by the path to the file. Suppose your subcircuit is `NTC.sub` and it's located in the same folder as your schematic, then you'd have to add this to your schematic: `.lib NTC.sub`, while taking care that your symbol has the right name and prefix. If what I said is fuzzy to you, then you'll need to polish up your knowledge on how to add custom models/subcircuits/symbols/etc in LTspice, see the help file for that.

Comment: The link i provided above under LTSpice model is all I could find from the manufacturer. The simulation file provided, I changed the symbol name in the simulation as well as the file of that symbol yet I I am getting the same error. Do you think I might need to change the spice code of the symbol itself? I checking for my specific models spice model but I couldn't find it. The only spice models I could find were the ones I mentioned above.

Comment: Based on the error, the symbol seems to have the correct prefix, but not the correct name (`ntc`), since I doubt the subcircuit has this definition inside: `.subckt ntc ...`.

Answer (score 1):

This particular P/N is not included in the library yet . It has the same characteristics as NTCLE101E3C90173 though. So if you are not concnerned about self heating, you can use this other P/N iso NTCLE413E2103F520L. If you open the library in LT spice you will see all the P/N included in this library. Not all the P/N are included